# What is the distance travelled by an electron in a solid conductor between succesive collisions?

Tags: electric-current

Suppose, we know that $\tau$ is the average time between succesive collisions, for finding the displacement, we can multiply $\tau$ with drift velocity, however, is it actually possible  to find out the distance  covered within succesive collisions?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *finding out*? It is not enough the drift velocity multiplied by $\tau$?

Comment: @Giorgio that should give displacement right? Not the distance covered

Comment: conductors are modeled with the band theory of solids, the electrons on the conduction band and the corresponding holes they leave do not scatter, more complicated modeling is needed see here to find the effective drift velocity of the electrons in the conduction band, afaik. see https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucapahh/teaching/3C25/Lecture21s.pdf

Comment: How do you imagine the motion of a conduction electron when you think the displacement is not the same as distance covered?

Comment: Within the approximations implied by a collisional model, I would not care about the difference between distance covered and displacement.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical model, the free electrons are bouncing around in thermal equilibrium with the atoms of the conductor. Their average speed would be:
V = $(3kT/m)^.5$ = d/ τ.
Where d is the average distance traveled between atoms on each bounce, and τ is the mean free time.  In each bounce, they are accelerated in the direction of electron flow by the electric field giving an average drift velocity:
v = [(eE/2m)$τ^2$]/ τ = eEτ/2m.
A previous question gives methods for finding v. Use that in my second equation to get  τ, and  τ in the first equation to get d.